# How to change array input value using index in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to edit a array input field using index
i tried like this

```js
$(document).on('click', '.changetext', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var index = $('.changetext').index(this);

  $('input[name="text[' + index + ']"]').val('ok changed');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changetext">
  <input type="text" name='text[]' value="">
</div>
<div class="changetext">
  <input type="text" name='text[]' value="">
</div>
<div class="changetext">
  <input type="text" name='text[]' value="">
</div>
```

I can get value using index like that

```js
$(document).on('click', '.changetext', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var index = $('.changetext').index(this);

  var field = $('input[name="text[]"]');
  alert(field[index].value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changetext">
  <input type="text" name='text[]' value="this is first field">
</div>
<div class="changetext">
  <input type="text" name='text[]' value="this is second field">
</div>
<div class="changetext">
  <input type="text" name='text[]' value="this is third field">
</div>
```

but i don't know how to change the value. if some one help me it would be appreciated

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, but are you just looking for `$(this).val('ok changed');` ?

Comment: All your names are `text[]` with no number in the brackets. So you won't get a match for a selector like `[name="text[0]"]`

Comment: sorry it was my first post . now i think it runnable code snippet.

Comment: @David `this` is the `div`, not the `input`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the index. The input is inside the div, so just use `$(this).find()` to get it.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.changetext', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).find("input[name='text[]']").val("ok changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changetext">
  <input type="text" name='text[]' value="">
</div>
<div class="changetext">
  <input type="text" name='text[]' value="">
</div>
<div class="changetext">
  <input type="text" name='text[]' value="">
</div>
```

However, if they weren't nested like this, you could use the index with `.eq()`, rather than substituting it into the `input[name="text[]"]` selector.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.changetext', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let index = $('.changetext').index(this);
  $("input[name='text[]']").eq(index).val("ok changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changetext">Change 1
</div>
<div class="changetext">Change 2
</div>
<div class="changetext">Change 3
</div>

1 <input type="text" name='text[]' value="">
<br>
2 <input type="text" name='text[]' value="">
<br>
3 <input type="text" name='text[]' value="">
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . sorry for my poor questioning skill . this can solve my problem . actually i need to store clicked index value some where so i could change value of clicked field after doing other functionality. I think now i can do it by using eq(index) .  thanks a lot you save me